# how many spaces contains in \t in java

Tags: java

```
public class Example1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("h\tw");
        System.out.println("h   w");
        System.out.println("hello\tworld");
        System.out.println("hello   world");


    }
}
```

this gave me the output below
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMll0.png)

In the first one \t = 7 spaces and in the second time \t= 3spaces
what is the reason for that?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Java.  It's more to do with the shell you're using to run it.  It looks like this particular shell lines things up every eight columns.

Comment: Netbeans also gave me the same output.

Comment: Yup, and so will C++, if you change "System.out.println" to "cout <<".  Or any other programming language, if you translate this code appropriately.  This isn't a Java question.  This is a "what shell am I using" question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tab works like the multiplication of 4 or 8 depending on the `console` you are using. You first console print contains 1 char `h` before a tab. So, there will be `7` space in between h & w. In the second case `hello` is `5` char long so there will be `3` space between hello and world.

Note: you mentioned there is 6 space between `h and w` but I believe it will be 7 space.
For the below example:

```
System.out.println("helloworld\tworld"); // line 1
System.out.println("helloworld      world");
```

Line 1 will generate `helloworld    world` as output. Now, `helloworld` has `10` char. I am assuming your console working on 8 multiplication principal. So, the lowest multiplication which is greater than `10` is `8*2 =16.` So there will be `16-10 = 6` space.

Comment: System.out.println("helloworld\tworld");  how many spaces should be in this statement? can you explain?

Comment: @WathsaraWishwanthaDaluwatta Please refer my edited answer

Answer (score 1):

Tab actually add a variable length but it has a maximum length. Just imagine tab-stops every 8 characters (just vertical lines where to stop is you use a tab)

```
|_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _|_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _|
```

If you use this strings "Hello\tWorld" it will move to the next tab stop after Hello.

```
|H E L L O _ _ _|W O R L D _ _ _|
```

Same applied to shorter length string like 'h\tw'

```
|H _ _ _ _ _ _ _|W _ _ _ _ _ _ _|
```